# Assigning "place" value to input in range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in range(n):  
    x=input()
```

I want `x` to have attached `i` values, is this possible without making a list?

For example, if `n == 3`, and I input `a`, `b`, then `c`, I want:

```
x(n-1) == b
```

Comment: Why don't you want to just create a list?

Answer (score 0):

you can use dict, if you're not willing to use lists:

```
In [81]: x={}

In [82]: for i in range(3):
   ....:     x[i+1]=input()
   ....:     
   ....:     
a
b
c

In [83]: x
Out[83]: {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}

In [84]: x[3]
Out[84]: 'c'
```

otherwise if our inputs are going to be only one character long ,then you can use a string too.

```
In [85]: x=''

In [86]: for i in range(3):
   ....:     x += input()
   ....:     
   ....:     
a
b
c

In [87]: x
Out[87]: 'abc'

In [88]: x[2]     # here index starts at 0th position
Out[88]: 'c'
```